# How to configure eclipse to ignore a (false?) error

Tags: eclipse, grails, twitter-bootstrap, scaffolding

I copied the templates from [here](https://github.com/robfletcher/twitter-bootstrap-scaffolding) to add scaffolding with Twitter Bootstrap thanks to the [twitter-bootstrap:2.3.2 plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/twitter-bootstrap).

`generates-all` works with no errors and creates everything with the look of Twitter Bootstrap.

But I get the next (false?) error:

```
- Groovy:unexpected token: < @ line 1, column 1.
```

At the next line of code:

```
<%=packageName ? "package ${packageName}\n\n" : ''%>import org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException
```

This is the Eclipse structure:

[image: false error?]

If it is just a mistake of eclipse, how could I tell it to ignore it?

Comment: Try clean and rebuild ? See if it works

Comment: `rebuild` does not look a Grails valid command. I tried `clean`, `compile` and `Grails Tools > Refresh Dependencies`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution so far is to comment out all the Controller.groovy class. The issue is that if I want to use "grails generate-all domain_class" I should remember remuving the comment previously.